# how can I get a dictionary to display 0 when something appears no times?

Tags: python

I want to search a list of strings for the letter a and create a dictionary that shows how many times it appeared. What I have now does this except when a doesn't appear it returns an empty dictionary. I want it to return {a: 0}. Here's what I have now in a function where its indented properly. what can i change in what i have now so that the created dictionary is {a:0}

```
list_strings = (["this","sentence"]
result ={}
for letter in list_strings:
    list_strings = list_strings.lower()
    for letter in letters:
        if letter == "a":
            if letter not in result:
                result[letter] = 0
            result[letter]=result[letter] + 1
return result
```

Comment: A dictionary doesn't "display" anything. If you to get back a zero for letters that weren't in your input, just use the `.get` method with a default: `result.get('a', 0)` will return the count for `a`, or `0` if `a` wasn't in the input...or it will, once you fix the other problems with your code.

Comment: That code doesn't work at all. You can't have `return` outside a function. See [mre].

Comment: Check out [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: Seconding the suggestion of collections.defaultdict. Also look at [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: Just for information, what would you want to return if the query here were on the letter "e"? 3, or 1?

Answer (score 1):

You can put {'a': 0} in the result ahead of time:

```py
result = {'a': 0}
```

And then do the next loop
If you want to count every letter in list of words, the defaultdict is useful.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

list_strings = ["this", "sentence", "apple"]
result = defaultdict(int)
result.update({'a': 0})
for word in list_strings:
    for letter in word:
        result[letter] += 1

print(result)
print(result.get('t', 0))
print(result.get('a', 0))
```

After that, you can take value by function: `get`, the second parameter is optional, if element not in dictionary, `get` will return the second parameter.

Comment: This doesn't really work, since it only provides the default value for one element.

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in the posted code.

Guess what you need is to count the number of "a"s in all the strings in `list_strings`  and store it in a dictionary. If there are no "a"s you need to be dictionary value for "a" to be 0.

You can initialize dictionary value "a" to zero at the beginning. I have corrected errors and do this in the below code.

```
list_strings = (["this","sentence"])
result ={}
result["a"] = 0
for string in list_strings:
    string = string.lower()
    for letter in string:
        if letter == "a":
            result[letter]=result[letter] + 1


print(result)
```

If you need to count other characters you can create the initial dictionary as follows.

```
d1 = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 0)
```

Comment: That only provides a starting value for one element.

Comment: Yes seems like the function only counts "a" s. If it is needed to count other characters, it is possible to create the starting dictionary for all lower case characters. I have updated my answer including that too.